# Size scale to convert psd> css ionic ## Escala de tamanho para converter psd> css ionic

Tags: css, ionic, photoshop

My designer made the mobile template in photoshop with 1080x1920.

How can I make proportional css?
In what size should it draw, for the measures of photoshop to be equivalent to the measures of css / ionic?

### pt-br:

Meu designer fez o mobile template no photoshop com 1080x1920.

Como consigo fazer o css proporcional?
Em que tamanho ele deveria desenhar, para as medidas do photoshop serem equivalentes com as medidas do css/ionic?

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro os breakpoints do próprio bootstrap:

- <= 768px: Smarthphones
- <= 992px: Desktop pequenos e tablets
- <= 1200px: Desktop grandes
- > 1200px: Desktops muito grandes (ex. full hd: 1920x1080)

Comment: mas pro desenvolvimento de APP/Ionic, acredito que isso não se encaixa.. Isso seria para desenvolvimento de sites mesmo... Estou procurando saber sobre APPS/Ioinic.

Obrigado pela resposta!